# Google Home Smart Home sync failing even though JSON is valid

Tags: google-cloud-functions, synchronization, actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

I am creating a Google Home smart home action. When I do the sync query, I get an error "No compatible devices were found in your curiousfly account. I have checked the documentation and tested my JSON in the Google Home Playground, and it seems to be valid. I am not sure what the issue is.

[
{
"id": "1234",
"type": "action.devices.types.FAN",
"traits": [
"action.devices.traits.OnOff",
"action.devices.traits.FanSpeed"
],
"name": {
"name": "load four",
"defaultNames": [
"load four"
],
"nicknames": [
"load four"
]
},
"willReportState": true,
"roomHint": "Room one",
"attributes": {
"reversible": false,
"availableFanSpeeds": {
"ordered": true,
"speeds": [
{
"speed_values": [
{
"lang": "en",
"speed_synonym": [
"1",
"one",
"One",
"minimum",
"Minimum",
"low",
"Low"
]
}
],
"speed_name": "1"
},
{
"speed_values": [
{
"lang": "en",
"speed_synonym": [
"2",
"two",
"Two"
]
}
],
"speed_name": "2"
},
{
"speed_values": [
{
"lang": "en",
"speed_synonym": [
"3",
"threeThreeMediummediumHalfhalf"
]
}
],
"speed_name": "3"
},
{
"speed_values": [
{
"lang": "en",
"speed_synonym": [
"4",
"four",
"Four"
]
}
],
"speed_name": "4"
},
{
"speed_values": [
{
"lang": "en",
"speed_synonym": [
"5",
"five",
"Five",
"maximum",
"Maximumhigh",
"High"
]
}
],
"speed_name": "5"
}
]
}
},
"states": {
"online": true,
"on": true,
"currentFanSpeedSetting": "1"
},
"suv": {
"enabled": false,
"challengeType": "pinNeeded",
"pincode": "1234",
"allowRetry": false,
"rejectErrorCode": "pinIncorrect"
}
},
{
"id": "C0D7AA7565E8",
"type": "action.devices.types.AUDIO_VIDEO_RECEIVER",
"traits": [
"action.devices.traits.InputSelector",
"action.devices.traits.MediaState",
"action.devices.traits.OnOff",
"action.devices.traits.TransportControl",
"action.devices.traits.Volume"
],
"name": {
"name": "YTU_I"
},
"willReportState": true,
"deviceInfo": {
"manufacturer": "smart-home-inc",
"model": "hs1234",
"hwVersion": "3.2",
"swVersion": "11.4"
},
"attributes": {
"volumeMaxLevel": 100,
"orderedInputs": false,
"availableInputs": [
{
"names": [
{
"lang": "en",
"name_synonym": [
"HDMI 1",
"DVD Player"
]
}
],
"key": "hdmi_1"
},
{
"names": [
{
"lang": "en",
"name_synonym": [
"HDMI 2",
"TV"
]
}
],
"key": "hdmi_2"
}
],
"volumeCanMuteAndUnmute": true,
"transportControlSupportedCommands": [
"NEXT",
"PREVIOUS",
"PAUSE",
"STOP",
"RESUME"
]
},
"states": {
"online": true,
"currentInput": "hdmi_1",
"on": true,
"currentVolume": 40,
"isMuted": false
},
"suv": {
"enabled": false,
"challengeType": "pinNeeded",
"pincode": "1234",
"allowRetry": false,
"rejectErrorCode": "pinIncorrect"
}
},
{
"id": "00f1-4b3b-ab2b-48aa1a3f7274",
"type": "action.devices.types.LOCK",
"traits": [
"action.devices.traits.LockUnlock"
],
"name": {
"name": "door"
},
"willReportState": true,
"deviceInfo": {
"manufacturer": "smart-home-inc",
"model": "hs1234",
"hwVersion": "3.2",
"swVersion": "11.4"
},
"attributes": {},
"states": {
"online": true,
"isLocked": false,
"isJammed": false
},
"suv": {
"enabled": false,
"challengeType": "pinNeeded",
"pincode": "1234",
"allowRetry": false,
"rejectErrorCode": "pinIncorrect"
}
},
{
"id": "4y74-453c-b034-c9746693f942",
"type": "action.devices.types.LIGHT",
"traits": [
"action.devices.traits.ColorSetting",
"action.devices.traits.Brightness",
"action.devices.traits.OnOff"
],
"name": {
"name": "Hue color lamp 1"
},
"willReportState": true,
"deviceInfo": {
"manufacturer": "smart-home-inc",
"model": "hs1234",
"hwVersion": "3.2",
"swVersion": "11.4"
},
"attributes": {
"colorTemperatureRange": {
"temperatureMaxK": 9000,
"temperatureMinK": 2000
},
"colorModel": "rgb"
},
"states": {
"online": true,
"color": {
"spectrumRgb": 16711935
},
"brightness": 100,
"on": true
},
"suv": {
"enabled": false,
"challengeType": "pinNeeded",
"pincode": "1234",
"allowRetry": false,
"rejectErrorCode": "pinIncorrect"
}
},
{
"id": "4y56-453c-l434-c9746693f942",
"type": "action.devices.types.LIGHT",
"traits": [
"action.devices.traits.ColorSetting",
"action.devices.traits.Brightness",
"action.devices.traits.OnOff"
],
"name": {
"name": "Hue lightstrip plus 1"
},
"willReportState": true,
"deviceInfo": {
"manufacturer": "smart-home-inc",
"model": "hs1234",
"hwVersion": "3.2",
"swVersion": "11.4"
},
"attributes": {
"colorTemperatureRange": {
"temperatureMaxK": 9000,
"temperatureMinK": 2000
},
"colorModel": "rgb"
},
"states": {
"online": true,
"color": {
"spectrumRgb": 16711935
},
"brightness": 100,
"on": true
},
"suv": {
"enabled": false,
"challengeType": "pinNeeded",
"pincode": "1234",
"allowRetry": false,
"rejectErrorCode": "pinIncorrect"
}
},
{
"id": "4y56-454587-b034-c9746675f942",
"type": "action.devices.types.LIGHT",
"traits": [
"action.devices.traits.ColorSetting",
"action.devices.traits.Brightness",
"action.devices.traits.OnOff"
],
"name": {
"name": "Hue second"
},
"willReportState": true,
"deviceInfo": {
"manufacturer": "smart-home-inc",
"model": "hs1234",
"hwVersion": "3.2",
"swVersion": "11.4"
},
"attributes": {
"colorTemperatureRange": {
"temperatureMaxK": 9000,
"temperatureMinK": 2000
},
"colorModel": "rgb"
},
"states": {
"online": true,
"color": {
"spectrumRgb": 16711935
},
"brightness": 100,
"on": true
},
"suv": {
"enabled": false,
"challengeType": "pinNeeded",
"pincode": "1234",
"allowRetry": false,
"rejectErrorCode": "pinIncorrect"
}
},
{
"id": "4y37-453c-b052-4545jkgii1bhh2b",
"type": "action.devices.types.AC_UNIT",
"traits": [
"action.devices.traits.FanSpeed",
"action.devices.traits.OnOff",
"action.devices.traits.TemperatureSetting"
],
"name": {
"name": "Dining"
},
"willReportState": true,
"deviceInfo": {
"manufacturer": "smart-home-inc",
"model": "hs1234",
"hwVersion": "3.2",
"swVersion": "11.4"
},
"attributes": {
"thermostatTemperatureUnit": "F",
"availableThermostatModes": [
"on",
"heat",
"cool",
"fan-only",
"dry",
"auto",
"off"
],
"availableFanSpeeds": {
"ordered": true,
"speeds": [
{
"speed_values": [
{
"lang": "en",
"speed_synonym": [
"Low",
"Slow"
]
}
],
"speed_name": "Low"
},
{
"speed_values": [
{
"lang": "en",
"speed_synonym": [
"Medium",
"Average"
]
}
],
"speed_name": "Med"
},
{
"speed_values": [
{
"lang": "en",
"speed_synonym": [
"High",
"Speed"
]
}
],
"speed_name": "High"
},
{
"speed_values": [
{
"lang": "en",
"speed_synonym": [
"Top Speed",
"Maximum"
]
}
],
"speed_name": "Top"
}
]
},
"_lastThermostatMode": "heat"
},
"states": {
"online": true,
"currentFanSpeedSetting": "Low",
"on": true,
"thermostatTemperatureSetpoint": 25,
"targetTempReachedEstimateUnixTimestampSec": 1696857817,
"thermostatTemperatureAmbient": 25,
"thermostatHumidityAmbient": 45,
"activeThermostatMode": "none",
"thermostatMode": "none"
},
"suv": {
"enabled": false,
"challengeType": "pinNeeded",
"pincode": "1234",
"allowRetry": false,
"rejectErrorCode": "pinIncorrect"
}
},
{
"id": "4y37-453c-b034-79cb6693f945",
"type": "action.devices.types.TV",
"traits": [
"action.devices.traits.Channel",
"action.devices.traits.InputSelector",
"action.devices.traits.AppSelector",
"action.devices.traits.MediaState",
"action.devices.traits.OnOff",
"action.devices.traits.TransportControl",
"action.devices.traits.Volume"
],
"name": {
"name": "Simple TV"
},
"willReportState": true,
"deviceInfo": {
"manufacturer": "smart-home-inc",
"model": "hs1234",
"hwVersion": "3.2",
"swVersion": "11.4"
},
"attributes": {
"availableChannels": [],
"volumeMaxLevel": 10,
"levelStepSize": 1,
"supportPlaybackState": true,
"availableApplications": [
{
"names": [
{
"lang": "en",
"name_synonym": [
"Youtube",
"Youtube_en"
]
}
],
"key": "youtube"
}
],
"orderedInputs": false,
"availableInputs": [
{
"names": [
{
"lang": "en",
"name_synonym": [
"HDMI 1"
]
}
],
"key": "hdmi_1"
}
],
"commandOnlyVolume": false,
"volumeCanMuteAndUnmute": false,
"volumeDefaultPercentage": 0,
"supportActivityState": true,
"transportControlSupportedCommands": []
},
"states": {
"online": true,
"currentInput": "hdmi_1",
"currentApplication": "",
"activityState": "STANDBY",
"playbackState": "STOPPED",
"on": true,
"currentVolume": 0,
"isMuted": false
},
"suv": {
"enabled": false,
"challengeType": "pinNeeded",
"pincode": "1234",
"allowRetry": false,
"rejectErrorCode": "pinIncorrect"
}
}
]

I was expecting to be able to sync my devices to Google Home successfully.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey, for me you have wrong payload. Check: https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/intents/sync, why u have a "states" parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this up. It seems the issue with account linking has been addressed and fixed. Please try linking the action again, and if the problem persists, consider reporting it on the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148) with recent logs and screenshots.